# SQL Like with wildcard returns wrong result on certain letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, wildcard, sql-like

I can't figure out why am i getting wrong result when using like keyword with wildcard. 
For the sake of discussion I've made small example to illustrate my problem.
Let's say we have some table

```
CREATE TABLE TestingLike(
[Name] VARCHAR(50)  
)

INSERT INTO TestingLike VALUES ('A'), ('AB'), ('L') ,('LJ')
```

Now when I use  this search criteria

```
SELECT [Name] FROM TestingLike WHERE [Name] LIKE 'A%'

SELECT [Name] FROM TestingLike WHERE [Name] LIKE 'L%'
```

First query returns **(A, AB)** while second returns just **L**. 
Strangely this is not happening when using temporary tables

For the love of god can someone please explain why is this happening,
I've done some research, but could not found the answer, I am using SQL SERVER RC1 2017 as well as SQL SMS.

Thank you for your time.

Below is the picture of execution plan

[image]

Comment: I'm betting your actual data has a leading white space in it... http://rextester.com/GIN97386 since as you should see, the sample data works as expected (with this exception)

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not happening when using temporary tables?" Can you provide an example case in your question? Do you literally mean not when creating a temp table (#tablename), table variable (@tablename), or...? Would like to duplicate this if possible.

Comment: Try putting a `union all` between the queries.  I suspect this is because only the first query is running.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I meant if i execute the same query using temp table `(#TestingLike)` , i will get expected result **(A,AB)** and **(L , LJ)**

Comment: I cannot replicate on [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f093d/7)

Comment: @Yollo you are using ASCII strings. Don't use ASCII strings unless you are *absolutely* sure you'll only store English text *in an English locale*. Add the `N` prefix to the string to convert it to a Unicode string and use an `*NAVRCHAR` field

Comment: BTW SQL Server doesn't have any issues with text or Unicode, in fact using Unicode is trivial. Problems are always caused when people use ASCII and inevitably mix up collations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot reproduce with a Latin collation but can if I'm using a Croatian collation, because in Croatian (and some other Slavic languages<sup>1</sup>), `Lj` is a single distinct letter formed from two characters, and is *not* `L` followed by `j`. [Lj (digraph)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lj_(digraph)) on wikipedia discusses this

You would not experience the same issue with temp tables/table variables if the collation for `tempdb` is different to the default collation for this specific database exhibiting the problem.

Complete/self contained repro script for those playing at home:

```
declare @TestingLike table(
[Name] VARCHAR(50) collate Croatian_CI_AI
)

INSERT INTO @TestingLike VALUES ('A'), ('AB'), ('L') ,('LJ')

SELECT [Name] FROM @TestingLike WHERE [Name] LIKE 'A%'

SELECT [Name] FROM @TestingLike WHERE [Name] LIKE 'L%'
```

---

How you go about "fixing" this depends on your overall goal. Your code is working correctly if it's playing by Croatian rules. Otherwise, you may need to change the default collation of the database. **But**, the default collation only applies when a column is *created*. So you'll also have to alter every existing column to change the collation to what you need.

---

<sup>1</sup>I use Croatian throughout my answer but I do, of course, mean "any collation where `Lj` is a digraph".

Comment: A good solution would be to use `nvarchar` and Unicode strings. Perhaps the only hassle-free solution

Comment: You can use COLLATE in your query, I used the following query to reproduce after reading your comment `SELECT [Name] FROM TestingLike WHERE [Name] LIKE 'L%' COLLATE Croatian_CI_AI;`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this will prevent the use of indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I've put a complete repro script in my answer. Even if you change all of the types/literals to `nvarchar`, it doesn't change the fact that under this *collation*, the two characters `Lj` are treated as a single letter.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever true, but it would eliminate the *conversion* between codepages that would happen otherwise. Right now the server uses one collation, the database another and it's anyone's guess what collation the *data* uses. It's quite possible that some data may result in conversion errors and `?` replacements.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yes, using Unicode will resolve many issues where the collation is having an impact of *what characters can be stored/represented*. But collations do two jobs - what can be stored (in non-`n` text types) and what comparison rules are in effect. The issue here relates to the latter, not the former.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you for your answer, I am using Seriban collation (same as Croatian) and `LJ` is treated as same character, but what about fixing this, after reading these comments i can't seem to decide what would be the right solution, altering tables would be time consuming, plus @JoakimDanielson  mentions that this will affect use of indexes

Comment: @Yollo - what needs fixing? `Lj` is not `L` followed by another letter. The results returned by `LIKE` were correct - the string was not `L` followed by any other set of letters.

Comment: @Yollo - if you want "strings that start with either `Lj` or `L`" then I think you should do `[Name] LIKE 'LJ%' or Name like 'L%'`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It still affects my search, because i would like to treat this as two letters (L and J), but this answer is very helpful and now I have multiple solutions, including your latest comment, thank you.